# How to use setTimeout() in Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I can't seem to use setTimeout() to call one of my own functions. I can use setTimeout to call alert(), but not a function that I've written myself. Here's the simplest code that reproduces the problem:

I have the following coffeeScript

```
    setTimeout(run, 1000)

    run = () ->
        console.log("run was called!")
```

Which generates the following Javascript

```
    // Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.3
    (function() {
      var run;

      setTimeout(run, 1000);

      run = function() {
        return console.log("run was called!");
      };

    }).call(this);
```

Nothing is printed to the console.

Comment: I don't know coffeescript but it looks like your trying to call a function where you should just be passing parameters / etc.

Comment: `setTimeout(() => { // Some code }, 1000);`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
run = () ->
    console.log("run was called!")
setTimeout(run, 1000)
```

You are relying on [javascript function hoisting](http://elegantcode.com/2011/03/24/basic-javascript-part-12-function-hoisting/) for functions declared with the syntax `function run(){}`, but coffeescript declares them as variables: `var run = function(){}`, so you have to define the function before you reference it, otherwise it's still `undefined` when you pass it to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 23):

## Anonymous Option:

Peter is exactly right. But you can also use `setTimeout` without declaring a variable:

```
setTimeout ->
    console.log 'run was called!'
, 1000
```

Yields:

```
(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        return console.log("run was called!")
    }, 1e3)
}).call(this);
```

Comment: how about garbage collection? possible in one go?

Comment: What is crucial in this answer is that there are 4 spaces before the `console.log` statement in coffeescript. If only 2 spaces, it won't work. In Coffeescript each tab or 2 spaces indents one level.

Comment: On one line: `setTimeout((-> someFunction()), 1000)`

Comment: 4 spaces are no longer crucial, or never was, or was but under some specific circumstances.